# Creating a page in wordpress that runs php code

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing my plugin that will create a page to user's wordpress and this page will be running php code in it.

I've read `Shortcode API` at wordpress `Codex` and `Page Templates` but those are for creating for my own wordpress content or maybe I am wrong.

Please help.

Comment: Where exactly are you having trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Need more details for your question but if you have a piece of php that you want to incorporate into a non-custom post-type, a shortcode may be your answer.  Call/reference the shortcode from the page/post using *[your_shortcode]*.

Define the shortcode in your plugin use the Wordpress function add_shortcode to make it available. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Comment: My plugin generates couple of checkboxes and a submit input, they will take value from user checks his checkboxes then use those value to query from wpdb. Sorry for my English